# Download all csv files from URL

Tags: python-2.7, csv, download, beautifulsoup

I want to download all csv files, any idea how I do this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = requests.get('http://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    print link.get("href")
```

Comment: You mean you want to download all csv files, linked from one page? I think iterating over all links and checking the file extension is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
import requests


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = requests.get('http://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
    for link in soup.findAll("a"):
        current_link = link.get("href")
        if current_link.endswith('csv'):
            print('Found CSV: ' + current_link)
            print('Downloading %s' % current_link)
            sleep(10)
            response = requests.get('http://www.football-data.co.uk/%s' % current_link, stream=True)
            fn = current_link.split('/')[0] + '_' + current_link.split('/')[1] + '_' + current_link.split('/')[2]
            with open(fn, "wb") as handle:
                for data in response.iter_content():
                    handle.write(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to filter the *hrefs* which you can do with  a *css selector*,*a[href$=.csv]* which will find the href's ending in *.csv* then join each to the base url, request  and finally write the content:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urlparse import urljoin
from os.path import basename

base = "http://www.football-data.co.uk/"
url = requests.get('http://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
for link in (urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in soup.select("a[href$=.csv]")):
    with open(basename(link), "w") as f:
        f.writelines(requests.get(link))
```

Which will give you five files, *E0.csv, E1.csv, E2.csv, E3.csv, E4.csv* with all the data inside.

Comment: it only prints response 200